# What should we do about questions containing dead links?

Tags: discussion, support, hyperlinks, broken-link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should we deal with questions that have broken links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99228/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-that-have-broken-links)

The following [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493339/control-list-item-float-position) contains a dead link. Because of the missing link the question doesn't make any sense anymore.

What should be done about this? Should it be flagged and, if so, as what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!** Flag the question for moderator attention, explain that it contains a dead link that makes the question now completely useless, and ask for it to be deleted. (You'll need to use the "other" option in order to provide this explanation.)

[image: This question contains a dead link to external code, which makes it completely useless. It should probably be deleted.]

As you mentioned, questions like this are *completely* useless to anyone now and serve no purpose. There's no good reason to leave them sitting around on the site.

This is why we discourage people from posting a link to code hosted elsewhere. We expect all questions asked on Stack Overflow to be *completely self-contained*, because link rot is a very real problem.

Related discussions:

- [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)
- [How should we deal with questions that have broken links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99228/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-that-have-broken-links)
- [Links to external content: How do we mitigate degradation of SO as external links begin to break over time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80621/links-to-external-content-how-do-we-mitigate-degradation-of-so-as-external-links)
- [Is it appropriate to include a link to a code sample on DropBox in an answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95679/is-it-appropriate-to-include-a-link-to-a-code-sample-on-dropbox-in-an-answer-to-a)

Comment: Question is a duplicate, but your screenshot on this answer is heaps better than your answer on the other Q...picture = thousand words?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a recent answer, leave a comment for the user.  If someone has already commented about the link and the user has failed to update, flag it.  If it is an old answer or the answerer is no longer here, flag it without commenting.

When you flag a new answer with a bad link, the only thing a mod can do is to leave a comment.  So, please think of the mods, and leave that comment for them.  If the poster doesn't care/can't care, go ahead and flag it and we'll delete.

Comment: You can tell if a user has been deleted if their flair is an anonymous blob person and their name isn't a link to a profile page.

Answer (score 0):

I would flag as very low quality. It seems to fit the definition. Even though the answers are good I doubt they will help without that link.